# Windows 8.1 Store: 2 ListViews Drag and Drop + Reorder

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I have a simple Windows Store App where I can drag and drop between two lists. See that awesome code below. :)

Now, as you can see I can reorder inside a given list. However, when I drag over a list, reorder does not occur. What do I need to do to have this happen? Will I need to create a custom control of sorts?

http://andrewherrick.com/spike/app1.zip

See my screenshot below: as I am dragging "Jax" and about ready to drop into list 2, I want "Andrew" and "Slick" to fly out, just like what happens when you reorder inside a given list.

[image]

Comment: Screenshot will be better to illustrate.

Comment: crea7or no problem hopefully that's clear enough?